# Remote MongoDB access through Cloud 9 gives login failed exception

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, cloud9-ide, mlab, database

I'm using the Cloud 9 IDE to develop an application using MongoDB. I created a database called "appdata" at [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/home) and the following user:

```
{
"_id": "appdata.admin",
"user": "admin",
"db": "appdata",
"credentials": {
    "SCRAM-SHA-1": {
        "iterationCount": 10000,
        "salt": "K/WUzUDbi3Ip4Vy59gNV7g==",
        "storedKey": "9ow35+PtcOOhfuhY7Dtk7KnfYsM=",
        "serverKey": "YfsOlFx1uvmP+VaBundvmVGW+3k="
    }
},
"roles": [
    {
        "role": "dbOwner",
        "db": "appdata"
    }
]
}
```

Whenever I try connecting to the database through Cloud 9 Shell using the following command (given by MongoLab with my newly created user):

```
mongo ds057244.mongolab.com:57244/appdata -u admin -p admin
```

I get the following error message:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.11
connecting to: ds057244.mongolab.com:57244/appdata
2015-11-22T05:23:49.015+0000 Error: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed",
code: 18 } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1292
exception: login failed
```

Also, on my javascript file running on Cloud 9, while following [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4) (which uses mongoose to access the DB) I got stuck on the post route for bears. Whenever I send a post request through postman with the specified fields set, the route doesn't return anything, neither a bear created nor an error message, which makes me think the problem is also failing to login to the database. The previous get request is working just fine and my code is the exactly same as the tutorial.

Does anyone know what the problem in any of the cases and what I need to do to solve them?

Comment: Have you checked out this: http://docs.mongolab.com/connecting/#help

Comment: Yea, it fails at the part where I check the credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The shell problem was fixed updating it to the Database version (which was 3.0.3).
2. For the javascript files, I restarted the tutorial and made sure I downloaded all necessary dependencies with the most recent stable version (not the ones shown on the tutorial), after that the problem was solved.